# Como gravar em um arquivo o número digitado pelo usuário e o valor dado pelo programa?

Tags: python

Como eu posso gravar apenas o valor digitado pelo usuário (o valor de n digitado por ele) e o resultado dado pelo programa (resposta) em um único arquivo?

```py
def fibonacci(n):
  
    r = [-1]*(n + 1)
    return fibonacci_2(n, r)
 
 
def fibonacci_2(n, r):
    
    if r[n] >= 0:
        return r[n]
 
    if (n == 0 or n == 1):
        q = n
    else:
        q = fibonacci_2(n - 1, r) + fibonacci_2(n - 2, r)
    r[n] = q
 
    return q
 
 
n = int(input('Digite um valor para n: '))
 
resposta = fibonacci(n)
print('O', n, 'termo da sequência de Fibonacci é:', resposta)
```

Answer (score 3):

Para realizar operações de ler e escrever em um arquive você deve fazer o seguinte:

```py
    arquivo= open( “nome_do_arquivo.txt”,”w” ) 
     
    arquivo.write( “valor providenciado pelo usuario: ” + str(n) ) 
    arquivo.write( “termo da sequência de Fibonacci é: ” + str(resposta) 
    
     
    arquivo.close()
```

segue a [referência da documentação do python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: é legal colocar um "\n" aí pra mudar de linha dentro do arquivo.